# Update status from viewholder on click android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have a shopping cart (Recycle View).
When you click on a product, it should change its state(change the background background and the status in the ROOM)
I thought to solve this problem like this:

When you click on the product update the product status in the ROOM and update the list of products and depending on the status change the color, but the problem is that when in the itemadapter I can not call viewlifecycleowner. It doesn't see it(
If I write this logic in a fragment, then I can't call this function from ViewHolder.
Please help

```
class OrderItemAdapter() : RecyclerView.Adapter<OrderItemAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private var mListProduct: MutableList<Product?>? = null
    private var mViewModel: OrderViewModel? = null

    constructor(viewModel: OrderViewModel, listProduct: MutableList<Product?>?) : this() {
        mListProduct = listProduct
        mViewModel = viewModel
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return if (mListProduct == null) 0 else mListProduct!!.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(position)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        return ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.frg_order_item, parent, false))
    }


    inner class ViewHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        private val title: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.product_name)
        private val count: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.product_count)
        private val price: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.product_price)
        private val btnEdit: Button = view.findViewById(R.id.product_edit)
        private val btnChange: Button = view.findViewById(R.id.button_change)
        private val productImage: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.product_image)
        private val btnDone: Button = view.findViewById(R.id.done)

        @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
        fun bind(pos: Int) {
            title.text = mListProduct?.get(pos)?.name
            price.text = mListProduct?.get(pos)?.price.toString()
            count.text = mListProduct?.get(pos)?.brgew.toString() + " " + mListProduct?.get(pos)?.gewei.toString() + "    " + mListProduct?.get(pos)?.quantity.toString() + " " + mListProduct?.get(pos)?.units.toString()
            view.setBackgroundColor(changerColorStatus( mListProduct?.get(pos)?.status!!))

            //count.text = pos.toString()
            productImage.downloadAndSetImage(mListProduct?.get(pos)?.pathImage!!)

            btnDone.setOnClickListener {
                val product = mListProduct?.get(pos)
                if (product != null) {
                    mViewModel!!.toCollectProduct(product.id!!)
                }
            }

            btnEdit.setOnClickListener {
                val product = mListProduct?.get(pos)
                if (product != null) {
                    view.findNavController().navigate(
                            OrderFragmentDirections.actionOrderFragmentToProductEntryDialogFragment(product)
                }
            }
            btnChange.setOnClickListener {
                val product = mListProduct?.get(pos)
                view.findNavController().navigate((OrderFragmentDirections.actionOrderFragmentToBarcodeScanningActivity()))
            }

        }
    }


    fun submitList(it: List<Product>?) {
        mListProduct = it?.toMutableList()
        notifyDataSetChanged()

    }


    fun changerColorStatus(statusProduct: StatusProduct): Int {
        return when (statusProduct) {
            StatusProduct.COLLECTED -> Color.GREEN
            StatusProduct.NOT_COLLECTED -> Color.YELLOW
            StatusProduct.EDIT -> Color.CYAN
            StatusProduct.REMOVED -> Color.GRAY
            StatusProduct.REPLACE -> Color.GRAY
        }
    }
}
```

**OrderViewModel**

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class OrderViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(private val ordersRepository: OrdersRepository) :
        ViewModel() {

    //TODO MAKE MUTABLE
    fun getBasket(id: Long): LiveData<Resource<List<Product>>> = ordersRepository.getBasket(id)

    fun toCollectProduct(id: Long) {
        ordersRepository.toCollectProduct(id)
    }

    fun updateFromLocalDB(id: Long) = ordersRepository.getOrderLocal(id);

}
```

**OrderFragment**

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@AndroidEntryPoint
class OrderFragment : Fragment() {
    private var orderId = -1L

    private val mViewModel: OrderViewModel by viewModels()
    private lateinit var mAdapter: OrderItemAdapter
    private lateinit var recycler: RecyclerView

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frg_order, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        recycler = view.chat_recycle_view
        arguments?.let {
            val safeArgs = OrderFragmentArgs.fromBundle(it)
            orderId = safeArgs.idOrder
            //TODO Log it
            setupRecycler()
            setupObservers()
        }
        fab.setOnClickListener {

            view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_orderFragment_to_barcodeScanningActivity)
        }
    }

    private fun setupRecycler() {
        recycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        val itemDecor = DividerItemDecoration(context, RecyclerView.VERTICAL)
        recycler.addItemDecoration(itemDecor)
        mAdapter = OrderItemAdapter(mViewModel, null)
        recycler.adapter = mAdapter
        chat_swipe_refresh.setOnRefreshListener { setupObservers() }
        // mViewModel.getBasket(orderId)
    }

    private fun setupObservers() {
        mViewModel.getBasket(orderId).observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            when (it.status) {
                Resource.Status.SUCCESS -> {
                    //binding.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                    isRefreshing(false)
                    if (!it.data?.isNullOrEmpty()!!) mAdapter.submitList(it.data)
                }
                Resource.Status.ERROR -> {
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), it.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    isRefreshing(false)
                }

                Resource.Status.LOADING -> {
                    isRefreshing(true)
                    //progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
            }
        })
    }


    private fun isRefreshing(refreshing : Boolean){
        chat_swipe_refresh.isRefreshing = refreshing
    }

    fun updateFromLocalDB(id: Long,view: View){
        mViewModel!!.updateFromLocalDB(id).observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            mAdapter.submitList(it)
        })

    }
}
```

Comment: If you can suggest any other solutions to the problem, I will be very happy

Comment: I dont really understand the problem here. You should not pass the viewModel to adapter. Just create interface that your fragment will extend and pass it to adapter. Then when item is clicked call the interface function that is implemented in fragment and here you should update your data in room. You can observe items state changes from room in your fragment and then update your items. Additionally you should not update whole list all the time but use payloads.

Answer (score 1):

First of all instead of Passing view model to adapter you should pass function (lambda or listener) to your adapter then your viewHolder like:

```
class Yourfragment  {
   val adapter = YourAdapter( { it:Int -> 
       // here you can use viewModel calls
   })
}

class YourAdapter(val clickFunc:(Int) -> Unit){
  // ...
}

// (Int)->Unit mean clickFunc is a function which gets integer as argument and return Unit

// then in your viewHolder.
init {
   itemView.setOnCLickListener{ clickFunc.invoke(adapterPosition) }
}
```